# Adding rows dynamically in ASP.NET core MVC not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Referring to the code below towards the end in the for loop, and in the javascript at the end...

When I click on the add button to add a row a few things happen...

Both the add & delete button id's do not change, they are supposed to iterate sequentially. It seems that the "-@i" isn't working in the button's id tag. Each row added shows the button id as "-0", but it should be -0, -1, -2 etc. for each row.

The delete button only becomes visible in the 1st row. It should become visible for subsequent rows. In the screenshot below, the 2nd row should show the delete button and hide the add button as shown in the 1st row.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of inspector]

Here is the Create.cshtml code

```
@model ResumeManager.Models.Applicant

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Applicant</h4>
<hr />

<div class="col-11 mx-auto p-0">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-primary text-uppercase text-white" style="height:45px;">
        <h4>Create Applicant</h4>
    </div>
    <form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Qualification" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Qualification" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Qualification" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TotalExperience" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="TotalExperience" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TotalExperience" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table" id="ExpTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Years Worked</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Experiences.Count; i++)
                {
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Experiences[i].CompanyName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
                       
                   </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Experiences[i].Designation, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
                       
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Experiences[i].YearsWorked, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
                        
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <button id="btnadd-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-secondary visible"
                            onclick="AddItem(this)">Add</button>
                        <button id="btnremove-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger invisible"
                            onclick="DeleteItem(this)">Delete</button>
                    </td>

               </tr>   
               }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastIndex" value="0" />

        </form>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-12 btn-group">
        <div class="col-6 form-group text-right p-2">
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 form-group text-left p-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>



<div>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function DeleteItem(btn){
        $(btn).closest("tr").remove();
    }
    
    function AddItem(btn){
        var table = document.getElementById("ExpTable");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;

        var lastrowIdx = document.getElementById("hdnLastIndex").value;
        var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;
        document.getElementById("hdnLastIndex").value = nextrowIdx;

        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("_" + lastrowIdx + "_", "_" + nextrowIdx + "_");
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("[" + lastrowIdx + "]", "[" + nextrowIdx + "]");
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("-" + lastrowIdx + "-" + nextrowIdx);

        var newRow = table.insertRow();
        newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;

        var btnAddID = btn.id;
        console.log(btnAddID);
        var btnDeleteid = btnAddID.replaceAll("btnadd", "btnremove");
        console.log(btnDeleteid);

        var delbtn = document.getElementById(btnDeleteid);
        delbtn.classList.add("visible");
        delbtn.classList.remove("invisible");
        
        var addbtn = document.getElementById(btnAddID);
        addbtn.classList.remove("visible");
        addbtn.classList.add("invisible");

    }

</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your js like this:

```
function AddItem(btn){
        var table = document.getElementById("ExpTable");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;

        var lastrowIdx = document.getElementById("hdnLastIndex").value;
        var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;
        document.getElementById("hdnLastIndex").value = nextrowIdx;

        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("_" + lastrowIdx + "_", "_" + nextrowIdx + "_");
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("[" + lastrowIdx + "]", "[" + nextrowIdx + "]");
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("-" + lastrowIdx , "-" + nextrowIdx);

        var newRow = table.insertRow();
        newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;

        var btnAddID = btn.id;
        console.log(btnAddID);
        var btnDeleteid = btnAddID.replaceAll("btnadd", "btnremove");
        console.log(btnDeleteid);

        var delbtn = document.getElementById(btnDeleteid);
        delbtn.classList.add("visible");
        delbtn.classList.remove("invisible");
        
        var addbtn = document.getElementById(btnAddID);
        addbtn.classList.remove("visible");
        addbtn.classList.add("invisible");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yiyi, that helped. I removed the quotes for those last two variables "delbtn" and "addbtn".  When a 2nd row is added, the delete button shows up on the first row. However, when I add a 3rd row, the delete button does not become visible on the second row, and the button id's of the added rows still show as "-0".  It seems that the elements for the buttons earlier in the code: "button id="btnadd-@i"", doesn't seem to be working. I should see the added rows of buttons show button id's of "btnadd-1, btnadd-2" etc. same for the delete buttons.
I edited the original post - added screen shot

Comment: Have you used ` rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("-" + lastrowIdx , "-" + nextrowIdx);` as I posted in my answer?

Comment: Goodness gracious I missed the comma lol. It works. I greatly appreciate the help!